# Get product custom fields in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

I'm writing a plugin for Craft Commerece that performs action on `commerce_orders.onOrderComplete`

I need to check the value of product custom field (Matrix) in order to determine action parameters.

I tried to use `$lineItem->purchasable->product->myCustomFieldHandle`, but this returns me `ElementCriteriaModel` without any data entered for product in this field.

Any ideas on how to get actual data saved in custom field for product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure it's the same for a product as it is for any other Craft element, like an entry.

To get simple fields:

`$lineItem->purchasable->product->myCustomFieldHandle`

To handle matrix fields, just loop through the matrix blocks:

```
$matrixBlocks = $lineItem->purchasable->product->matrixFieldHandle; 
foreach ($matrixBlocks as $block){
    echo $block->id;
    echo $block->fieldHandle;
    if ($block->fieldHandle == "whatever"){
          etc
    }
}
```

Certainly that works with SuperTable fields on a product, pretty sure it's the same with matrix fields.